# How to allow org-insert-link to accept mail addresses like 'Name <name@some.address>'?

Tags: org-mode, email

When I add a mailto link with `C-c C-l`, the closing `>` is missing.

If I enter:

```
mailto:Apa <apa@bepa.cepa>
```

Leaving the description blank, I get a link like

```
mailto:Apa <apa@bepa.cepa
```

If I end with `>>`, the link is correct. If I enter it with markup like below, it works.

```
[[mailto:Apa <apa@bepa.cepa>]]
```

This comes from the following snippet of `org-insert-link` (Emacs 24.4.1)

```el
(if (and (string-match org-plain-link-re link)
         (not (string-match org-ts-regexp link)))
    ;; URL-like link, normalize the use of angular brackets.
    (setq link (org-remove-angle-brackets link)))
```

So modifying `org-plain-link-re` or `org-ts-regexp` is one way to achieve this. These are pretty impressive expressions, which looks a bit intimidating to touch.

I understand that `<>` tags are used by org, and this is the likely reason for these types of mail links not getting treated like one would naively think, but I also can't believe I'm the only one that uses addresses of this type.

So has anyone tweaked emacs org to accept this, or is it a bug, or is this address format considered evil?

Comment: I think this sounds like a bug.  This should work out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `org-remove-angle-brackets` is responsable for actually striping the "<>" from the link, we can fix this by adding some advice saying that if the link starts with "mailto:", just return the link, otherwise do whatever the original function does.

```el
(advice-add #'org-remove-angle-brackets :before-until
            (lambda (s) (if (string-prefix-p "mailto:" s) s)))
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Maybe I'll gather some courage and report it as a bug...

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting a URL, and `' '` (space), `<>` (angle brackets), `"` (double quotes) are not valid characters in a URL, and so must be encoded.

- `' '` becomes `%20`
- `"` becomes `%22`
- `<` becomes `%3c`
- `>` becomes `%3e`

So, the email address:

```
Apa <apa@bepa.cepa>
```

is expressed as a URL like this:

```
mailto:%22Apa%22%20%3capa@bepa.cepa%3e
```

which is a chore to write.

Ideally, Emacs would check whether the entered link uses the `mailto:` URL scheme and encode the special characters for you. In the meantime, perhaps some advice?

Comment: Tried to find some info about what format it does expect, but didn't find much.  The info page shows an example with a simple address. Cheers for the info, the advice from @erikstokes does the trick.